# Why is fs.writeFile throwing an err? Why and I getting an error in the first place?

Tags: node.js

**code:**

```
  // Save the image
  fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data) {
    var imagePath = path.join(nconf.get('imagePath'), imageOrig.substring(0,6), imageOrig);
    console.log('Saving image: ' + imagePath)
    fs.writeFile(imagePath, data, cb);   // Line 120
  });
```

**error:**

```
Saving image: /Users/username/Development/appName/public/images/2120A2/2120A232-4D6E-EFC4-672C-668C20C024C0.jpg

fs.js:113
    throw new Error('Unknown encoding: ' + encoding);
          ^
Error: Unknown encoding: /Users/username/Development/appName/public/images/2120A2
    at assertEncoding (fs.js:113:11)
    at Object.fs.writeFile (fs.js:939:3)
    at /Users/username/Development/appName/lib/routes/fileName.js:120:12
    at fs.js:266:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

**question 1:**

Why is is throwing? shouldn't the error be passed to the callback `cb`?

**question 2:**

Why am I getting the error? The image being uploaded is a valid jpeg. If I change the line to this `fs.writeFile(imagePath, data, { encoding: null }, cb);` then it saves the image (I can see it and open it with an external image viewer), but never calls the callback function `cb` so the request is never ending.

Comment: According to the error, `cb` is set to a path `String`, the base directory for images, rather than the expected callback `Function`. Where and how is `cb` defined?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - ugh. async.series, not async.waterfall. Used the wrong one. thank you. Write up an answer and I'll mark it correct.